Best Kafka topic migration strategy
Looking forward to dive deep in most optimal design strategy for Kafka topic migration.
I am publishing to two topics. Topic-1(legacy) topic-2 (new topic)
I want my consumer to migrate to new topic topic-2. How to do this migration with no consumer downtime and no loss of data.
Topic 1 and topic-2 are not guaranteed to be in sync and publish at same time , will have same data flow though.
Strategy-1
Start consumer on topic-2 with reading from earliest message on Kafka.

slow and too much lag can generate but complete solution if able to process enormous data

Reset offset validation and getting offset from consumer

You can subscribe to multiple topics at the same time. Remove the first topic when all producers are done
